# Only select year from date

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series

My dataframe look like this:

```
            mth account_type interest_rate
1057 1977-01-01      Special           6.5
1061 1977-02-01      Special           6.5
1065 1977-03-01      Special           6.5
1069 1977-04-01      Special           6.5
1073 1977-05-01      Special           6.5
...         ...          ...           ...
3077 2019-02-01      Special             5
3081 2019-03-01      Special             5
3085 2019-04-01      Special             5
3089 2019-05-01      Special             5
3093 2019-06-01      Special             5
```

I like to collapse "mth" column to just year

```
            mth account_type interest_rate
1057       1977      Special           6.5
...         ...          ...           ...
3093       2019      Special             5
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your column `mth` is already `datetime`:

```
df['mth'] = df['mth'].dt.year
```

If it is a `string` you have to first convert to `datetime`:

```
df['mth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['mth'])
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add a column with the year:

```
df['year'] = df['mth'].dt.year
```

And then you can group  the info by year and do for example an `.mean()`

```
df.groupby((["interest_rate"]).mean()
```